# 'fn' is null or not an object in require-jquery.js Line:2813

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

We have this wired error that is not reproduciable but rondomly happening.
it throw error on this line/function in Jquery:
        **proxy: function( fn, context )** {

Here is the code that trigger this problem. It is used for screen rotation, it throw error in **setTimeout($.proxy(function...** :

```
    _showPanel: function(index) {
        // go to first panel, index is out of range
        var index = (index > this._panels.length - 1) ? 0 : index,

        // calculate next panel index
            nextIndex = (index + 1) % this._panels.length,
            panel = this._panels[index],
            oldPanelElement = this._currentPanelElement;


        // set timer when to switch to next panel
        this._panelRotationTimeout = **setTimeout($.proxy**(function () {
            if (this && this._showPanel) {
                this._showPanel(nextIndex);
            }
        }, this), panel.time);


        // hide old panel
        if (oldPanelElement) {
            oldPanelElement
                .hide()
                .detach();
        }

        // show/hide animation
        if (panel.animation) {
            this._animation.show();
        } else {
            this._animation.hide();
        }

        // show new panel
        this.element.find('.panelContainer')
            .append(panel.element);
        panel.element.show();

        // update status and button
        this._updateDisplay();

        // track current panel details
        this._currentPanelIndex = index;
        this._currentPanelElement = panel.element;

        this._currentDeviceStatusIndex = index;
    },
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in this specific line

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout`'s first argument should be a function. In your example you're actually calling the $.proxy giving `setTimeout` the return value of $.proxy function. Try passing it an anonymous function and do your stuff inside it:

```
setTimeout ( function() { $.proxy ( ...
```

Comment: the $.proxy method DOES return a function. This also doesn't match the error being thrown.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was posting this answer from my smartphone walking home in a heavy rain and didn't bother to check jQuery documentation.
Now I've read the jQuery.proxy documentation and for me it all seems to work.  I can't find the problem in the code you provided.  
Can you provide some more examples? A jsfiddle, maybe?

Comment: This issue is randomly happening. 99.9% time it works fine. When the error happen, the application is running "setTimeout($.proxy...", then it is inside the require-jquery.js calling proxy: function( fn, context ) {
it looks like the anonymous function passed in become null or out of scope.

Comment: What is this `require-jquery.js` script? Is it just jQuery library? If so, which version?

Comment: require-jquery.js is just require.js and jquery.js combined together in one file.   RequireJS 2.1.2 and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.1

Comment: Well, I didn't have any contact with RequireJS but it has a [complete separate section](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) in the documentation which explains how to use this library with jQuery. Did you read it and consider all suggestions mentioned there? You could especially pay attention to [global vars](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#globalvars) section which mentions [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) function. Anyways, I think you should try embedding `jQuery` without `RequireJS` in the first place.